# How to explode with double line break in PHP?

Tags: php, explode, line-breaks

I want to `explode` a text to separate paragraphs and tried

```
$array = explode("\n\n", $str");
```

but it is not a practical approach since double line breaks can be in the form of

```
\n \n
\r\n\r\n
```

or other formats and `\n\n` is not always the case.

Is there a safe approach to `explode` double line breaks (or ideally all multi-line breaks)?

Comment: you can try with <br> if want output in html

Comment: Use a preg_replace to normalise the new lines / spaces, then explode on the common delimiter?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu it has nothing to do with HTML or browser output. It is about organising the text entries in a database.

Comment: hmm you should use replacing functions that i didn't understanded pretty well sorry :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) : regex `explode`

```
$array = preg_split("/(\n\s\n){1,}|(\n){1,}|(\r\n){1,}/", $str);
```

`(\n\s\n){1,}`: Line break, Space, Line break, unlimited combo.

`(\n){1,}`: Line break, unlimited combo.

`(\r\n){1,}`: Line break, unlimited combo.

`/`: Enclosing the parameters with forward slash delminators.

If you want to replace it with `<br>`: [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) :

```
$str = nl2br($str);
```